# Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I get the following error when accessing most pages on my site. Sometimes some of the pages load, sometimes not.

Disallowed Key Characters

www.claireyaffa.com

Answer (score 2):

ok. I'm pretty sure, that you have this problem, because your site ask for cookies with name **__utmt_~1**. And "**~**" is Disallowed Key Characters. __utmt is Google Analytics cookie. I think, that it is happens because you have two Google Trackers on your page:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-8460157-1");
```

&

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-9184900-1");
```

Try to remove one of this.
Possible you will need to cleanup cookies after that.

Comment: I've been getting this problem too but can only find one  set of analytics code. The only thing I could do was disable that code. I wonder if it's an external service (such as Typekit) which has started using Google Analytics.

Comment: Indeed, I just tested and it seems to be the fact I was also using Typekit. Removed that and it stopped setting the extra GA cookie.

Comment: This was a very old Typekit set and republishing it removed the GA cookie it was setting.

Comment: Thank You... I was able to remove one of the analytic codes and it works fine....